# "К нашему ужину дюжину..."

Tags: литература

Как-то на одном сообществе зашел разговор о стихотворениях Чуковского, в частности об известных строчках: "К нашему ужину дюжину / Новых и сладких калош".
Так вот, интересно, почему крокодилы у Чуковского питаются калошами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А. Дошкольное воспитание, 1929, №4).

"... у Чуковского и его соратников мы знаем книги, развивающие суеверие и страхи ("Бармалей", "Мой Додыр", "Чудо-дерево"), восхваляющие мещанство и кулацкое накопление ("Муха-цокотуха", "Домок"), дающие неправильное представление о мире животных и насекомых ("Крокодил" и "Тараканище"), а также книги явно контрреволюционные с точки зрения интернационального воспитания детей" Дошкольное воспитание, 1929, №4).

Б. Наши современники о Чуковском

"Во времена Корнея Ивановича Чуковского калоши делались из натурального каучука и были качественные, вкусные и безвредные для здоровья крокодила (это такая  жевательная резинка)". "Не хочу сказать про Корнея Ивановича ничего плохого. Все мы в детстве зачитывались его произведениями. Но сейчас перечитываешь его книги с детьми, и закрадывается подозрение,что поэт иногда употреблял легкие наркотики и рифмовал все подряд.Очень богатая фантазия была у этого человека".

В. Комментарий

Детские книги Чуковского - это поэзия абсурда и гротеска, доступная детям, но не очень понятная взрослым. В них два важных начала. Во-первых, это звукопись: "чёткий ритм, звонкие рифмы, музыкальные сочетания звуков, которые так легко и весело повторять". Во-вторых, игра в смысловые  "перевертыши", это тоже нравится маленьким читателям.

Answer (score 5):

Это просто шутка. Ожидается, что крокодилы будут их носить, а они их едят.

Ср. с анекдотом (да простят меня за его некоторую неприличность):

> > -Доктор, Вы мне свечи выписывали. Не помогают, живот как-то крутит, подташнивает.
> >
> > -Вы что их жрёте, что ли?
> >
> > -Нет, блин, в ... засовываю!

Answer (score 4):

Потому,  что  это  сказка.  Мир  сказочный  живёт  по  законам  сказочным  -  здесь  можно  все,  что  невозможно  в  мире  обычном.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, во времена Чуковского калоши были предметом первой необходимости, дети их носили и знали, что калоши нужны всем, даже крокодилам.

А во-вторых, в голодные годы калоши действительно ели. Так что крокодил вел себя вполне логично с точки зрения детей той эпохи (стихотворение написано в 1924 году, как раз после гражданской войны).

У Чуковского крокодил - персонаж с ригидной психикой (застревающей, негибкой, зацикленной). Привыкнув есть калоши в годы войны, он продолжает их есть и тогда, когда их можно носить и не простужаться. Что-то вроде странноватого дедушки-ретрограда с устаревшими привычками, за которым нужен глаз да глаз, а то наестся гадости и заболеет.

Comment: Вопрос  только  один - о  съедобности  резины,  даже  натуральной. Где,  когда  и  как ?